# mutate_if only being applied to one column (can't see my error)

Tags: r, dplyr

As the title implies, I can't see where I am going wrong using mutate_if.

**Reproducible example**

```
# Create a data frame
 df <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17904, 17905, 17906),
                                   class = "Date"),
                 item_1 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8),
                 item_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 9),
                 item_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 2),
                 item_4 = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0)),
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)) 

> df
        dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
1  2019-01-01     NA     NA     NA     NA
2  2019-01-02      1     NA     NA     NA
3  2019-01-03      2     NA     NA      1
4  2019-01-04      3     NA      8      2
5  2019-01-05      4      1      9      3
6  2019-01-06      5      2     10      4
7  2019-01-07      6      3     11      5
8  2019-01-08      7      0      0      6
9  2019-01-09      0      0      0      0
10 2019-01-10      8      9      2      0


# Create a function to be used with mutate_if
my_fx <- function(x) {
    if_else(!is.na(x), cumprod( c(100, 1 + x[-1] / 100) ), NA_real_)
}


# Create a new data frame using mutate_if on original data frame
new_df <- df %>%
mutate_if(.predicate = is.numeric,
          .funs      = funs(index_val = my_fx)
          ) 

> new_df
        dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4 item_1_index_val item_2_index_val item_3_index_val item_4_index_val
1  2019-01-01     NA     NA     NA     NA               NA               NA               NA               NA
2  2019-01-02      1     NA     NA     NA         101.0000               NA               NA               NA
3  2019-01-03      2     NA     NA      1         103.0200               NA               NA               NA
4  2019-01-04      3     NA      8      2         106.1106               NA               NA               NA
5  2019-01-05      4      1      9      3         110.3550               NA               NA               NA
6  2019-01-06      5      2     10      4         115.8728               NA               NA               NA
7  2019-01-07      6      3     11      5         122.8251               NA               NA               NA
8  2019-01-08      7      0      0      6         131.4229               NA               NA               NA
9  2019-01-09      0      0      0      0         131.4229               NA               NA               NA
10 2019-01-10      8      9      2      0         141.9367               NA               NA               NA
```

The output I expected was that the function would apply to the other columns (e.g.,  "item_2", creating a new "item_2_index_val") but those columns are all coming up NA.

I can't see what I am missing here, but I am hoping it is something simple.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The issue is your function, not your `mutate_if`. Run `my_fx(df$item_2)`, - the result is all NA.

Comment: You may need `replace`

Comment: Ah, indeed Gregor.  Hmmm.  Now how to fix the function?  Akrun, can I ask what you are thinking on replace?  I was thinking the way the function would work is that it would take a column as a vector and step through the values--if the value was NA, it would keep it NA, otherwise it would carry out the calculation

Comment: Thanks Akrun, looking at now.  Seems to work and I will mark correct shortly.  One question, can you explain the val line?  The solution works, but interestingly when I run the val line alone it throws an error.

Comment: Not clear about the error, I subset the data with logical index (`x[i1]`)

Comment: I pulled each line out of the function to run separately to follow the logic.  When I do that to the val line it generates an error, but I believe that is because that line is expecting to operate on a column vector vs. a data frame, which it does when inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with how the `NA` values are getting used in the `cumprod` which can return `NA` for all values even if there is a single `NA`.  In order to make sure that we are only applying the `cumprod` into non-NA elements, extract the non-NA elements with an index ('i1') -> `x[i1]`, remove the first element, concatenate with 100, apply `cumprod` and then `replace` the `NA` vector with the 'val' based on 'i1'

```
my_fx <- function(x) {
     new <- rep(NA_real_, length(x))
     i1 <- !is.na(x)
     val <- cumprod( c(100, 1 + x[i1][-1] / 100) )
     replace(new, i1, val)
   }
df %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, list(index_val = ~ my_fx(.)))
#        dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4 item_1_index_val item_2_index_val item_3_index_val item_4_index_val
#1  2019-01-01     NA     NA     NA     NA               NA               NA               NA               NA
#2  2019-01-02      1     NA     NA     NA         100.0000               NA               NA               NA
#3  2019-01-03      2     NA     NA      1         102.0000               NA               NA         100.0000
#4  2019-01-04      3     NA      8      2         105.0600               NA         100.0000         102.0000
#5  2019-01-05      4      1      9      3         109.2624         100.0000         109.0000         105.0600
#6  2019-01-06      5      2     10      4         114.7255         102.0000         119.9000         109.2624
#7  2019-01-07      6      3     11      5         121.6091         105.0600         133.0890         114.7255
#8  2019-01-08      7      0      0      6         130.1217         105.0600         133.0890         121.6091
#9  2019-01-09      0      0      0      0         130.1217         105.0600         133.0890         121.6091
#10 2019-01-10      8      9      2      0         140.5314         114.5154         135.7508         121.6091
```

Also, as thee `NA`s are at the top, this can be achieved more easily with

```
f1 <- function(x) cumprod( c(100, 1 + x[-1] / 100))
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, list(index_val = ~ 
                c(rep(NA_real_, sum(is.na(.))), f1(na.omit(.)))))
```

---

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(df)[-1]
nm2 <- paste0(nm1, "_indexval") 
setDT(df)[, (nm2) := NA_real_]
f1 <- function(x) cumprod( c(100, 1 + x[-1] / 100))
for(j in seq_along(nm1)) {
   i1 <- which(!is.na(df[[nm1[j]]]))
    set(df, i = i1, j = nm2[j], value = f1(df[[nm1[j]]][i1]))
  }

df
#         dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4 item_1_indexval item_2_indexval item_3_indexval item_4_indexval
# 1: 2019-01-01     NA     NA     NA     NA              NA              NA              NA              NA
# 2: 2019-01-02      1     NA     NA     NA        100.0000              NA              NA              NA
# 3: 2019-01-03      2     NA     NA      1        102.0000              NA              NA        100.0000
# 4: 2019-01-04      3     NA      8      2        105.0600              NA        100.0000        102.0000
# 5: 2019-01-05      4      1      9      3        109.2624        100.0000        109.0000        105.0600
# 6: 2019-01-06      5      2     10      4        114.7255        102.0000        119.9000        109.2624
# 7: 2019-01-07      6      3     11      5        121.6091        105.0600        133.0890        114.7255
# 8: 2019-01-08      7      0      0      6        130.1217        105.0600        133.0890        121.6091
# 9: 2019-01-09      0      0      0      0        130.1217        105.0600        133.0890        121.6091
#10: 2019-01-10      8      9      2      0        140.5314        114.5154        135.7508        121.6091
```

---

The key is that we are only removing the first element `x[-1]` which could be NA, but there are also other elements that are `NA`

Comment: Why would this not work (remove the [-1])?  my_fx <- function(x) {
    if_else(!is.na(x), cumprod( c(100, 1 + x / 100) ), NA_real_) }    For example, take column item_3:  Does the x here represent the entire vector, or each element in the vector?  In other words, if the first element in a column = NA, then would the first element in the mutated column be NA, and so on until you hit the 4th element = 8.  Since 8 is not NA (!NA = True), then would the cumsum begin at that 4th element (8), or is the cumsum taking the whole item_3 column? Doesn't if_else go element by element?

Comment: @dave_in_newengland  Just out of similarity in user namess, I gues you are not the OP, right

Comment: What is OP?  New to R and trying to follow a lot of the posts here.  I didn't understand the answer.  The " list ~ " is also confusing.  I won't even try to understand the data.table for now.

Comment: @dave_in_newengland  Sorry, I meant OP as original poster.  Regarding removing the `-1` ie. the first element, it is in the OP's function.

Comment: dave_in_NE, try this to see the answer (takes whole column).  Note cumsum does not have an na.rm = True argument.    f1 = function(x) sum(x)
f2 = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
f3 = function(x) if_else(!is.na(x), sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), NA_real_)
f4 = function(x) if_else(!is.na(x), cumsum(x), NA_real_)

df %>% mutate_if( is.numeric, list(~ f1(.)) )
df %>% mutate_if( is.numeric, list(~ f2(.)) )
df %>% mutate_if( is.numeric, list(~ f3(.)) )
df %>% mutate_if( is.numeric, list(~ f4(.)) )

Comment: Sorry for the formatting...tough to format code in comments

Comment: I owe you the thanks akrun.  You are a machine!  You have answered a ton of questions and have saved me a lot of time.